# Use username column as slug (friendly_id)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want the users on my rails app to access their profile (users/show.html.erb) with a domain.com/username URL. I have it working, but the issue is that the **slug** column in the users table is an exact duplicate of the **username** column. Is there a way to simplify this and use **username** as the **slug**?

If you think this a bad idea, and it's better to have them in separate columns let me know why also.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :username
```

no need to add `slug` column